# Where is the option that lets me edit code which is running in the debugger and then continue with the changes compiled?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

By luck, sometimes I can edit a class while the debugger is running and sometimes not (on different machines eg a colleague's at work).

As title states, where is the option that lets me edit code which is running in the debugger and then continue with the changes compiled?

I am using Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition SP1.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Tools/Options/Debugging/Edit and Continue.  It's often the case that you won't see the options as the other user may have ticked the 'Don't show this again' checkbox when the prompt first comes up. This dialog lets you reset those options.

Answer (score 0):

I think "edit-and-continue" is only supported for x86 binaries, so if you're running 64-bit target, you won't be able to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what pave_m said, you have to be in debug mode, not in release mode.